# how to extrude along face normals evenly?

Tags: modeling, extrude

Please see the attached pic. I've researched many ways to extrude faces evenly but none of the methods I have seen will actually do it evenly. They all result in face A being extruded far less than face B. What am I doing wrong here?  It's like there is some weighting going on somewhere , somehow. If I create a long cuboid in a fresh scene and try it , it works as expected... all faces extrude an even amount. I'm getting this happen all over this mesh though so I need to fix it in this scene really.

Strangely, if i create a new cuboid in this scene I get the faulty results.. Is there something wrong with the scene?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In This case the problem was that the mesh object had non-uniform scale transformations. The solution was to Apply the transforms Ctrl - A , then choose Scale.